# In DoubleCommander, how to show last visited times for files?

Tags: file-management, double-commander

In DoubleCommander Windows version, how to show last visited times for files?

Comment: By "last visited times", do you mean last accessed or last modified dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Goto Configuration -> Options -> Columns -> Custom collumns.
2. On the Date row, click on its "Field contents" field. Click on the `+`, then DC.
3. Select Access date/time. Click OK.

[image]

Comment: How does one actually apply it?

Comment: @qazwsx I don't understand your question. Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: After doing what you described and clicking "Save" or "OK", I'm not seeing the new column of access time in the main view. Instead, it is like the default look before. What is missing?

Comment: I did not add a new column. To add a new column, on the Custom columns windows, right-click on the grid, click Add column. Give the new column a name, set the field content, etc.

Comment: I did what you described. Still, it seems the customized view must be applied or turned on somehow, right? How? Because, as I said, going back to the main window, the look is still the old and default one.

Comment: @qazwsx I am able to add a new column with no issue. In this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKnWC.png), I added a new column for the creation time.

Comment: @qazwsx I reached here because I had exactly the same question. After some lookaround I found how to do this. You right click on the top part of the folder view (where you have the column headers), in the context menu you can choose to apply your custom view. When editing the view you would have saved it with a different name - if not, do that first.